# Countdown timer with pause/reset

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm looking for an open source JavaScript timer that will countdown from 60 seconds. I would prefer if people could increase the timing on the timer, but that's not necessary. It is necessary for people to be able to start and pause the time and reset it when they need to.

A tutorial or source code would be great.

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Have you searched on Google (or your favorite search engine)?

Comment: I did and couldn't find what I was looking for.  I need something that is very close to what I'm looking for because I know very very little javascript and so I can't really edit other people's code.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution in pure javascript to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/XcvaE/4/

Answer (score 3):

This should give you a good start. This timer will fire a "Hello" alertbox after 30 seconds. However, everytime you click the reset timer button it clears the timerHandle and then re-sets it again. Once it's fired, the game ends.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerHandle = setTimeout("alert('Hello')",3000);
    function resetTimer() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("alert('Hello')",3000);
    }
</script>

<body>
    <button onclick="resetTimer()">Reset Timer</button>
</body>
```